# bijectivity of $Φ$ ensures that $Φ$ is exactly global analytic isomorphism

Tags: elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces

This is a question from Silverman's book 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves', chapter Ⅵ.

If $\Lambda$ is a lattice in $\Bbb C$ the map
$$z\mapsto (\wp(z),\wp'(z))$$
is a parametrisation of the complex points of the elliptic curve
$$E:\qquad y^2=4x^3-g_2x-g_3$$
where $g_2$ and $g_3$ depend on $\Lambda$. It induces a group
isomorphism $Φ$：$\Bbb C/\Lambda\to E(\Bbb C)$ : $t\mapsto (\wp(t),\wp'(t))$ .

To show this is isomorphism as Rieman surface, the books reads **it is enough to prove $Φ$ is local analytic isomorphism ( because $Φ$ is bijective).**

So, we only need to check

Φ*(dx/y)＝$d\wp(z)/\wp'(z)$＝$z$・・・①.

Once ① is proved, this is holomorphic and non vanishing at every point of domain, so $Φ$ is local analytic function.

My question: Why is is enough to show that $Φ$ is local analytic isomorphism ? Why bijectivity of $Φ$ ensures that $Φ$ is exactly global analytic isomorphism?

Comment: The bijectivity of $\Phi$ ensures that $\Phi^{-1}$ is defined. As $\Phi$ is a local analytic isomorphism, by “holomorphic inverse function theorem” $\Phi^{-1}$ is locally analytic, so it’s analytic. QED

Comment: How $Φ$ and inverse of $Φ$ is locally analytic deduces $Φ$ is (global) analytic ?

Comment: A locally analytic function is analytic on its domain of definition... so apply that to $\Phi$ and its inverse (which is defined since $\Phi$ is bijective).